# How to create multiple html tables and display employee details dynamically For each department name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two tables one is employees and one is department i want to create html table for each department name and display employees details of specific department dynamically
How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you using Entity framework on server side and have relation between table then you can use code like below

```
public class Departments
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult DepartmentList()
{
    List<Departments> deptList = GetDepartments();
        List<Employee> empList = GetEmployee();

        foreach (Departments dept in deptList)
        {
            dept.EmployeeList = empList.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == dept.DepartmentID).ToList();
        }

        return View(deptList);
}
```

And .cshtml page

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Controllers.Departments>

...

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            @item.DepartmentName
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var emp in item.EmployeeList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @emp.EmployeeID
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @emp.EmployeeName
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

May this help you

Thanks

Comment: I am using Linq to Sql